# Get first three bits from a byte

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, hex, byte, bit

My question is simple, i need to convert the first three bits of a byte to a integer (Enum) value. However the things i try i always get a 0 back. This is wat the document says:

`Bit 0-3: These bits indicate the connection state.`

`Value 0 to 14 indicate the connection state. Value 3 = Connected`

Now the response i get (from a serial device) is a encoded byte stream of ASCII hex values, so i first need to convert it from a hex string to byte array and then get the bits from it. This is my code so far:

```
Dim strResonse As String = "0C03" 'This should result in a connection state value of 3

Dim ConState(2) As Byte
ConState = HexStringToByteArray(strResonse)
Dim int As Integer = ConState(1) << 1 And ConState(1) << 2 And ConState(1) << 3
Debug.Print(int.ToString)


Private Function HexStringToByteArray(ByVal shex As String) As Byte()
    Dim B As Byte() = Enumerable.Range(0, shex.Length).Where(Function(x) x Mod 2 = 0).[Select](Function(x) Convert.ToByte(shex.Substring(x, 2), 16)).ToArray()
    Return Enumerable.Range(0, shex.Length).Where(Function(x) x Mod 2 = 0).[Select](Function(x) Convert.ToByte(shex.Substring(x, 2), 16)).ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: If the relevant values are 0 to 14, that's 4 bits, not 3.  the_lotus has provided what should work, see their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to use bit operation

```
Dim connectionState As Integer
Dim response As Integer = &HC03

' Get the first 4 bits. 15 in binary is 1111
connectionState = response And 15
```

If your input is really a string, there a built-in way to convert to integer.

```
Dim response As Integer = Convert.ToInt32("C03", 16)
```

If you really want to get an array, I suggest you use the built in method.

```
Dim allBits As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(response)
```

There also the [BitArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=netframework-4.8) class that can be handy.

Comment: Hi Lotus, that for you explanation, i tried some stuf and i can't seem to get the only first three bits of one byte and convert that to a integer/enum. The remaining bits (4 - 7) are reserved for other information

Comment: Should work, fairly easily: Dim int As Integer = Convert.ToInt32("C03", 16) & 15

Comment: When i try that i get a result of 307515. The string i enter is `0C03` because this is exactly what i get from the serial device.

Comment: I meant, AND not &. sorry about that.  Dim int As Integer = ConvertConvert.ToInt32("C03", 16) And 15